# Getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried imitating my code in simple steps on python prompt:

```
>>> path="D:/workspace/a/b\\c\\d.txt"
>>> path[0,18]
```

But it gives me following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I wanted to retrieve only directory as path. That is, I want to strip away the file name: `D:/workspace/a/b\\c`

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: `path[0:18]` not `path[0,18]`. The `:` is your problem

Comment: `path[0,18]` is parsed by Python as "look up index `(0, 18)` in the path", and you can't index a string by a tuple

Comment: The index styling you used works for 2d arrays.  If `arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,1]])` then `print (arr[0,4])` will result in `4`. This is just to show that `[0,4]` is not wrong and works on 2d arrays but not on the string you provided.

Answer (score 2):

`path[0,18]` should be `path[0:18]` or `path[:18]`

Even better (will work not matter what length the parent directory is):

```
import os
os.path.split(path)[0]
```

Comment: Or you can use the function `os.path.dirname` which is pretty much the same thing, but a little more explicit

Comment: Literally the same in fact but it is more explicit `def dirname(p):
    """Returns the directory component of a pathname"""
    return split(p)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with regex as well

```
import re
result = re.sub(r'\\[a-z]*.txt',  '',    path)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
path="some/again_a_dir/file.txt"
print(path[0:16])
```

When we want to get a range of letters from the string, we should use ":" to define the range. `path[0:16]` means get items from the 1st element to 17th element of your string.